# '%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'' don't work on Python3.5

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I dont work on Jupyter Notebook. This code works on jupiter but I want to run it on normal python. When I run the code, I get the following error.

```
import cv2
from darkflow.net.build import TFNet
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How will I solve this problem? Could you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the last row `%config ...` is for the Jupyter graphic rendering configuration only. It wont work outside of it. Just remove it, and your code will work.